# .NET HTTPClient not connecting to previously connected hosts

Tags: .net, tcp, dotnet-httpclient

In the last several months, our Azure application has been having a lot trouble connecting to various hosts.  We are getting errors like:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

When working with one of our hosts, we found they had recently changed their firewall which changed a bunch of TCP rules.  Of of these has something to do with a socket keep-alive setting.  Our app was set to 4 minutes, I believe.  Their firewall was set to 20 minutes.  They were kind enough to set their timeout to 4 minutes and the errors stopped.  However, this is just one host.  There are several others that are getting the same/similar errors and they will not adjust their firewalls for us.  (It seems like they should not have to either.)

Using .NET 4.7.2 with HTTPClient to connect, we have tried changing the KeepAlive and requesting Close in the header.  These settings have not had any effect. I am no TCP expert, but it appears that the connection is left half-open.

Microsoft says they have not made any changes.  This part of our code has not been changed and has been working for a couple years.  Now suddenly these errors are happening and everyone says they didn't make any changes.

We have never gotten these errors in dev environment.  Also, it seems to only happen when the servers are the most busy, like morning hours.

Is there anyway to force/strongly request that the host firewall reset the connection?
We have retry logic that will attempt multiple times to submit the request when we get these errors, but only about 1 in 3 will eventually succeed.

When doing wireshark on the client that changed their firewall, we found that the packets we sent never made it past the firewall.  It's like we say, "Hey there! Here's a connection request with a data request." to which the firewall says, "You already have a connection, so I'm not going to respond to you."  Then the packet gets lost.

Any ideas on how we can fix this in .NET on our application side?

Comment: Are any of the points addressed in this post true of your solution? https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @TomW Yes, thank you.  We came across this a week or 2 back and made some code changes to ensure it was followed. However, the errors persist.

Comment: In our latest attempt to resolve this, we followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#benefits-of-using-ihttpclientfactory  Unfortunately, it didn't seem to have any effect.